# Navigate between Login and Dashboard page

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF. I'm creating a POS desktop application by using WPF MVVM pattern as front-end development. (I have try my best to make this question as short as possible.)

**Scenario:** I have a `MainViewModel` which will show `AuthView` (and AuthViewModel) by default whenever user open the application. After user fill in the form and click the *Login* button in `AuthView`, `LoginCommand` will be called on the view, if login successful, they will be redirect to `DashboardView`.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        if (SelectedViewModel == null)
        {
            SelectedViewModel = new AuthViewModel();
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedViewModel = new DashboardViewModel();
        }
    }

    private ViewModelBase _selectedViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return _selectedViewModel; }
        set { _selectedViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel)); }
    }

    public void ChangeToDashboard()
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new DashboardViewModel();
    }
}
```

**AuthViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class AuthViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public AuthViewModel()
    {
        loginCommand = new RelayCommand(Login);   
    }


    #region Login
    private RelayCommand loginCommand;
    public RelayCommand LoginCommand
    {
        get { return loginCommand; }
    }
    private async void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            Response = await callLoginAPI; //some custom login occurs here

            if (Response.Status == "ok")
            {
                //change viewModel to DashboardViewModel screen
                MainViewModel MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
                MainViewModel.ChangeToDashboard();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

**Problem:** I have go through a lot of SA solution but still unable to switch the view after user login successfully.

**Question:** How can I trigger the MainViewModel to change UI after I have change the `SelectedViewModel` property (after user login successfully, response.status == ok)? or is there any other better (as simple as possible) way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AuthViewModel can generate event about login

```
public class AuthViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public AuthViewModel()
    {
        loginCommand = new RelayCommand(Login);   
    }

    public event EventHandler LoginCompleted;

    protected virtual void OnLoginCompleted(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = LoginCompleted;
        handler?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private RelayCommand loginCommand;
    public RelayCommand LoginCommand
    {
        get { return loginCommand; }
    }
    private async void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            Response = await callLoginAPI(); //some custom login occurs here

            if (Response.Status == "ok")
            {
                OnLoginCompleted(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

and MainViewModel can handle that event:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        if (SelectedViewModel == null)
        {
            var vm = new AuthViewModel();
            vm.LoginCompleted += (sender, e) => ChangeToDashboard();
            SelectedViewModel = vm;
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedViewModel = new DashboardViewModel();
        }
    }

    private ViewModelBase _selectedViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return _selectedViewModel; }
        set { _selectedViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel)); }
    }

    private void ChangeToDashboard()
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new DashboardViewModel();
    }
}
```